# CSOM error with SP.SOD.executeFunc used twice

Tags: 2010, client-object-model, jquery, csom

I'm trying to do several CSOM requests. But I can't do it. 
Here is my first, that works alone :

```
    var collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = "";
    var enumeratorRevente;
    var numOccurrencesTotRevente = 0;

    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function(){
      getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeTot();
    })


    function getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeTot() //this function called on button click to get ID's
    {
         collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = "";
         enumeratorRevente;
         var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
         var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel revente finale');
         var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
         camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View> <Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef  Name='ID' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query> </View> ");
         collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
         clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente);
         clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeTot, getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeTot);
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeTot()
    {

        numOccurrencesTotRevente = collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente.get_count();
        setValue();            
    }
    function getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeTot(sender, args)
    {
        alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }



    function setValue() {

        $("#revente_count_tot").text(numOccurrencesTotRevente).toString();
    }
```

The second is near of this one, it should work but SharePoint doesn't let me do this function :

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', null, function(){
      getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj();
    })
```

Seems like I can't use that to launch my func, I have "request failed". But when I put the function without `SP.SOD.executeFunc`... I have an **undefined**!

**EDIT**

Here is what I tried:

```
var collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = "";
var enumeratorRevente;
var numOccurrencesTotRevente = 0;

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){ 
getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeTot(); 
getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj(); 
});

function getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeTot() //this function called on button click to get ID's
{
     collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = "";
     enumeratorRevente;
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel revente finale');
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
     camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View> <Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef  Name='ID' Ascending='True' /> </OrderBy> </Query> </View> ");
     collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
     clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeTot, getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeTot);
}
function getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeTot()
{

    numOccurrencesTotRevente = collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente.get_count();
    setValue1();            
}
function getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeTot(sender, args)
{
    alert('Request failed1. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



function setValue1() {

        $("#revente_count_tot").text(numOccurrencesTotRevente).toString();
}


var collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = "";
var numOccurrencesMajRevente = 0;

function getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj() //this function called on button click to get ID's
{
     collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = "";
     enumeratorRevente;
     var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Matériel revente finale');
     var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
     camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Mise à jour parc'> <Value Type='Text'>Non</Value> </FieldRef> </Eq> </Where> </Query> </View> ");
     collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente = oList.getItems(camlQuery);
     clientContext.load(collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente);
     clientContext.executeQueryAsync(getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeMaj, getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeMaj);
}
function getItemsToBeUpdatedSuccess1ReventeMaj()
{

    numOccurrencesMajRevente = collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente.get_count();
    setValue2();            
}
function getItemsToBeUpdatedFailed1ReventeMaj(sender, args)
{
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



    function setValue2() {

        $("#revente_count").text(numOccurrencesMajRevente).toString();
    }
```

Now I have this error *one-or-more-field-types-are-not-installed-properly*

Comment: You show us the code that works, but don't actually show us the code that's not working (`getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj` and its associated success/fail functions). Can you show us that code? It sounds like there's a problem with it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Ok I do it tomorrow. I didn't do it because the code works alone, as for the one I show you. The problem comes from the line I told you (I think). But no proble I edit my answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: Ok I've edited my answer to provide all code you can need

Comment: looks like I can't launch two functions

Comment: You'll need to use the internal names of your columns in the query, not their display names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Amal Hashin said, you've opened a `<FieldRef>`, but you should close it like that : `<FieldRef Name='Mise à jour parc' /> <Value Type='Text'>Non</Value>`

Also I saw a mistake in your code. You use `collListItemToBeUpdatedRevente`as variable to print the result of the query. The problem is that you use that variable several times in the two functions. Thereby, I think your first CAML query result should be empty, am I right ?

**You should do the following :**

For the function `getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeTot()`, use the variable `collListItemToBeUpdatedReventeTot`.

And for the function `getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj()`, use the variable `collListItemToBeUpdatedReventeMaj`.

After that, both your query results should not be empty. However, I don't know what should make your CAML query.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is wrong. Try below query instead

```
camlQuery.set_viewXml("<View> <Query> <OrderBy> <FieldRef Name='Mise à jour parc'> </FieldRef> </OrderBy> </Query> </View> ");
```

Comment: yeah thanks I already did the update with a good query I think, but still a problem. I have this error : one-or-more-field-types-are-not-installed-properly

Comment: That means you are not using proper field internal names. Use the list settings page to get the proper name.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function(){
      getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeTot();
      getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj();
    });

Hope this should work.

or you can also try with

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeTot");
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getItemsToBeUpdatedReventeMaj");

Comment: thanks but I've understood that the error comes from the camlQuery, it goes to the failed eventually

Comment: Now the query is good, I've updated the second code part. But I have this error : one-or-more-field-types-are-not-installed-properly

Comment: check the column names